# How to display title of the many markers at the same time when the activity starts

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to display the title of the many markers' at the same time when the activity starts. Markers are generating dynamically.I have more than 5 markers.

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
marker.position(position);
marker.title(name);
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on marker for" + " " +
                (String) marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop and call showInfoWindow() for all the markers.